# Build a custom Apache Storm rpm from source?

Tags: apache-storm

I am trying to build an RPM based on the latest 0.9.x branch, because the version 0.9.6 contains a critical bug fix but there is no official release for that version.

When I build my RPM and run it, I get this message:

> ---
>
> The storm client can only be run from within a release. You appear to be trying to run the
>   client from a checkout of Storm's source code.
>
> You can download a Storm release at
>   http://storm-project.net/downloads.html
>
> ---

This blog describes how to build the from source:

http://blog.pangyanhan.com/posts/2014-04-04-how-to-build-the-storm-client-from-source.html

But it instructs to run this command:

> `chmod a+x bin/build_release.sh bin/build_release.sh`

I cannot find the build_release.sh script, I believe it was removed since that blog posting.

Any suggestions on how I can build a custom 0.9.x RPM?

Comment: Did you have a look here: https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/DEVELOPER.md#packaging It's for the current master (0.11.0-SNAPSHOT) but there might be an older version for 0.9.x, too.

Comment: Thanks, I'll read through that.

Answer (score 1):

This error message tells you have downloaded the wrong file. If you have a look at the file it will probably be about 1.5mb. You have downloaded the client only. Download the server and client version (it should be about 77.5mb).

[Here is the current correct link](http://mirrors.ae-online.de/apache/storm/apache-storm-0.10.0/apache-storm-0.10.0.tar.gz).

unpack this and look into the subfolder examples (i recommend using intellij IDEA (15.03). In examples, you will find samples of topologies you can compile (via mvn clean package)).

i personally have a virtual machine with (CentOS version 6) running and followed the instructions [here](http://jansipke.nl/installing-a-storm-cluster-on-centos-hosts/).