# Storm 1.0.2 : mvn install results in build failure

Tags: python, maven, apache-storm

I've just installed storm 1.0.2 and when I try to compile the storm-starter package, it results in a build failure:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.132 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-01-25T18:24:05-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 40M/2434M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal 

    org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.2.1:process (default) 
    on project storm-starter: Error finding remote resources manifests: 
    /home/patrick/storm-starter1.0.2/target/maven-shared-archive-resources/META-INF/NOTICE 
    (No such file or directory) -> [Help 1]

    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal 
    org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.2.1:process (default) 
    on project storm-starter: Error finding remote resources manifests

at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)

Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error finding remote resources manifests
at org.apache.maven.plugin.resources.remote.ProcessRemoteResourcesMojo.processResourceBundles(ProcessRemoteResourcesMojo.java:1204)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.resources.remote.ProcessRemoteResourcesMojo.execute(ProcessRemoteResourcesMojo.java:519)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
... 20 more

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/patrick/storm-starter1.0.2/target/maven-shared-archive-resources/META-INF/NOTICE (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
```

I didn't change the examples/storm-starter/pom.xml file that came with the storm release.

The default python on my server is 3.5.2 (I don't know if it can be an explanation). Storm 1.0.2 is supposed to be Python 3 compatible. I'm clueless, any hint is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you try out cloning repository and build from root maven?

Comment: Could you be more explicit, I'm a little bit new to java, maven, etc. Cloning storm repository? I'm not sure about the exact signification of "build from root" but I git clone storm repo and in the examples/storm-starter, I did a mvn clean install: same result.

Comment: "Build from root" means "mvn clean install" from root directory. It handles some works so you might need to do this before building storm-starter separately. You can also do "mvn clean install -DskipTests" from root directory, and "mvn clean install" from storm-starter directory.

Comment: I understand from what you say that root directory and storm-starter directory are different. But what is the root?

Comment: The directory which contains doap_Storm.rdf, LICENSE, NOTICE, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much Jungtaek for your help, it worked.

Comment: OK I'll move my suggestion to answer. Please accept the answer once I move.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving comments to the answer.

Storm root pom handles some works so you might need to "build from root" (via executing `mvn clean install` with/without `-DskipTests`) first.

After that you can build storm-starter via `mvn clean install` from storm-starter directory.

> "Root directory" means the directory which contains doap_Storm.rdf,
>   LICENSE, NOTICE, etc.

Comment: May I ask you a follow up question: so after git clone repo and mvn clean install, I'm back in my ~/apache-storm-1.0.2 directory. There (in examples/storm-starter directory) I can now build without problem (I guess the mvn install from the root handled work needed before building storm-starter as you said). Now if I try to do the same in ~/apache-storm-0.10.2/examples/storm-starter directory, it results in the same build failure I had before (see above). Do you see why?

Comment: Artifacts seems not installed locally for 0.10.2. You need to build from root for also 0.10.2.

Comment: I built from root for 0.10.2 and it builds without failure. I built from storm-starter directory with success. Now when I try to run a topology, it says that "The storm client can only be run from within a release. You appear to be trying to run the client from a checkout of Storm's source code."

Comment: I understand from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32377813/build-a-custom-apache-storm-rpm-from-source that I probably downloaded the wrong file. I downloaded the src distribution (http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/storm/apache-storm-0.10.2/apache-storm-0.10.2-src.tar.gz) because the non-source has no pom.xml at the root (and consequently I cannot build from the root). What can I do?

Comment: Please refer this link to package binary dist from sources. 
https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/DEVELOPER.md#packaging

If you don't want to modify Storm code and just want to use, you just need to download binary distribution and extract and have fun using it.